# how to apply sortBy for two columns. in laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, sorting, eloquent

my product table contains these datas

| id | name | price | discounted_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

I want to apply sorting to table product using laravel eloquent. the discounted_price is 0 then sorting apply to price. discounted_price not 0 then sorting apply to discounted_price.

Comment: Hi ! I would like to clarify a point. When you say that `discounted_price is 0 or not 0 `, are you implying that 0 is a value that you retrieve from request input or somewhere else ?

Comment: 0 is the value of discounted_price in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply retrieve all items using Eloquent `get()` method. After that, iterate through the collection and at each iteration, check if the `discounted_price` is `!= 0`. If the condition is true, simply append a new item called `final_price` to the collection, with the value of `discounted_price`. Else, append the `final_price` with the `price`.

Finally, use `sortBy()` method to sort the collection by the `final_price`

```
        $products = Product::get();

        foreach($products as $product) {
            if($product->discounted_price != 0) {
                $product->final_price = $product->discounted_price;
            } else {
                $product->final_price = $product->price;
            }
        }

        return $products->sortBy(['final_price','asc']);
```

Further reference on collections sorting - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$products = Product::all();

return $products->map(function ($product) {
    $isDiscountPrice      = $product->discounted_price !== 0;
    $product->final_price = $product->{$isDiscountPrice ? 'discounted_price' : 'price'};
    return $product;
})->sortBy(['final_price','asc']);
```

In this situation, [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map) Laravel Collection  would be a good solution !